# Pass by reference avoids object slicing

Tags: c++

```
class Pet {
public:
    virtual string getDescription() const {
        return "This is Pet class";
    }
};

class Dog : public Pet {
public:
    virtual string getDescription() const {
        return "This is Dog class";
    }
};
```

suppose i have a function which takes argument of bas class type like

```
void describe(Base obj) {
   p.getDescription();
}
```

and i pass derived class object in this function, so the object will be sliced and we ll get output rerlated to base class.

But if i modify this function and make it like

```
void describe(Base& obj) {
   p.getDescription();
}
```

and again passes derived class object, this time output will be of derived class.

I couldnt understand how pass by reference avoides object slicing.

Comment: While not strictly true, a reference is basically just a fancy pointer.So when you pass a reference, you really pass a pointer to the *actual* object.

Comment: Aren't you really just asking what the slicing problem is?

Comment: No, I know the object slicing concept. I got confused in pass by refernece but now  got the answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: it is related to pass by reference..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The derived object gets "sliced" when it is used to instantiate a base class object. This happens when you pass by value, because the function parameter is a base class object, not anything else. It is the equivalent of doing this:

```
Derived d;
Base b = d; // b is a Base, not a Derived. It knows nothing of Derived.
```

A reference is simply an alias for an object, so a reference to a `Base` object does not involve the construction of a new `Base` object. It simply aliases one:

```
Base& b = d; // b aliases d, i.e. a Derived object
```

After the above statement, `b` is an alias for `d` and can be use to access `d`'s `Base` interface polymorphically. It can alias a `Derived` object because `Derived` ***is-a*** `Base`. This wouldn't be possible with, say, private inheritance.

Comment: Technically it is possible with private inheritance, see [class.access.base]/3